# Present tense referring to the immediate past

Tags: tenses

I recently read Claudian's *In Rufinum* with Harry Levy's commentary. Towards the end of the poem, Claudian describes the change of fortune of the slain Rufinus (2.451-2.452)

> . . . iacet en, qui possidet orbem,
> exiguae telluris inops . . .

The use of the present *possidet* is jarring to me, because Rufinus is dead and no longer in power. Levy comments:

> the present tense ironically stresses the suddenness as well as the awfulness of Rufinus' fate: "Lo, he who until this moment possesses the world, lies. . ."

This is a charming interpretation, but Levy does not supply parallel instances of a present verb referring to the immediate past. Are there examples from other authors of this use of the present tense? Is this use of the present documented in a grammar book?

Comment: I don't read Levy referring to any "immediate past"; rather, it seems to be precisely that if the preset tense would have been frequented for "immediate past", then the note by Levy would lose its force.  In other words, as I see it, the point that if present tense is "jarring to you" than the poet made a good job; Levy, then, is merely helping the readers who seamlessly read the present test and notes its significance.

Comment: @d_e If Claudian meant the line to be read as Levy translates it, then I agree that Claudian did an excellent job. I'm curious if there are any parallels to support translating "possidet" as "until this moment possesses". In his translation Levy adds the words "until this moment" to give a past force to the present verb in English. So it surprises me that "possidet" by itself (without an adverb, for example) can have the meaning Levy gives it.

Comment: I think this is what the grammar books call the historic present, or the dramatic present, or the narrative present. It seems to be more common in some writers than in others.